# does function location in c++ matter?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int my_variable = 12;
void cappy()
{
    std::cout<<"value is"<< my_variable<<endl;
}

int main()
{
std::cout<< my_variable<<endl;
cappy();
}
```

this c++ code work and returns:

```
12
value is12
```

but whereas :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int my_variable = 12;

int main()
{
std::cout<< my_variable<<endl;
cappy();
}

void cappy()
{
    std::cout<<"value is"<< my_variable<<endl;
}
```

this code returns an error:

```
cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
cpp:8:7: error: ‘cappy’ was not declared in this scope
```

why is this so? does location of functions matter in c++?

Comment: Declare the function before you use it

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between a definition and a declaration?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410563/what-is-the-difference-between-a-definition-and-a-declaration)

Comment: Good question man, thinking critically and practicing like you are is the best way to learn!

Answer (score 5):

The function needs to be *declared* before it is used. Besides that, it doesn't matter. So you can have this:

```
void cappy(); // declaration

int main()
{
  cappy();
}

void cappy() // definition
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It happens because in c++ the compiler reads through the file once and isn't "smart enough to know" that this is a future function that is being called.  So you could declare the function earlier, or make a header file declaring all the functions you will be using.